# Custom command like execute-extended-command

Tags: completion, commands

I want to implement a custom `M-x` (`execute-extended-command`).
This time real skeleton-coding (crying)

```
(defun gbq-extended-command (inst) 
  (interactive "sgbq-X ")
  (cond ((equal inst "eob") (end-of-buffer)))
  ;; BODY of function
  )
```

in this function, I want completion instruction. for example, if call the function, like `M-x`, when I type `eo`, Completion from `eo` to `eob`. 
but I have no idea how.

Comment: Are you aware of the key sequences `C-<end>` and `C-<begin>`? If you want to have shortcuts for existing commands consider also `defalias`.

Comment: @Tobias Thanks for your Comment!! but, i want own 'M-x'. So wondering that implementation. but i dnt want reinventing the wheel T.T, Hmm, another way you know that rename from 'M-x' to 'gbq-X' as Text when call the M-x!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the definition of `execute-extended-command` for inspiration (in `simple.el`, reachable via the link in `C-h o execute-extended-command`)?

In any case, to prompt the user in the minibuffer with completion, you want to use the `completing-read` function (about which you can read in the Elisp manual).

Comment: yaya!! in completing-read , i get try-completion! Thanks for your answer. my knowledge level up ,  this is for you!